# Hibernate - Is there any way to get the name of the column for which a Constraint was violated?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, maven

I'm using Hibernate to save Entities in a Database.

On the Entity fields (columns), I have defined a lot of Constraints (such as NotNull or length=10).
When a Constraint is violated, a ConstraintViolationException is thrown. I want to somehow be able to track for which column a constraint was violated.
The ConstraintViolationException in the Java-Library "javax.validation.ConstraintViolation" has a method "getConstraintViolations()" so I can just do

> `constraintViolationException.getConstraintViolations().getPropertyPath()`

which should give me the column name.

However, the ConstraintViolationException thrown by Hibernate does not have a method "getConstraintViolations()" and there doesn't seem to be anything like it.
My only option now would be to analyze the String returned by calling "getConstraintName()":

> `constraintViolationException.getConstraintName()`

But this seems kind of messy and not secure.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the column name?

EDIT:

Relevant dependencies inside the pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: The message option? `@Email(message = "Invalid email") @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter email") private String email;` and  `violation.getMessage()`

Comment: I wonder how you get hibernate `ConstraintViolationException`. Can you provide a minimal example of your configuration, e.g. `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`?

Comment: @DirkDeyne I annotate most of my Class fields with @Column(). I did not find something similar to "message" there :/ Is it better to change the Annotations to get this done?

Comment: this may help [hibernate-notnull-vs-nullable](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-notnull-vs-nullable) ?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz I added the dependencies in the EDIT to my question. I think these are the relevant ones to my question.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? Maye you could share the whole `pom.xml`? Setting up a small project, I get `javax.validation.ConstraintViolation`s...

Comment: @DirkDeyne So I seem to be able to remove most of my constraints from the \@Column Annotation in order to label them. But how do I do it when I want a class field to be unique? With \@Table(\@UniqueConstraint(...)) ? Seems a bit complicated :D

Comment: Refactoring your constraints as suggested by @DirkDeyne will solve your problem

Comment: @weirdVariable You cannot control some constraints on the data before accessing the database (e.g. @NotNull) but you cannot find out if unique key constraint will be violated before accessing the database. So do not expect to get a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolation` for all of your constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing things.

**Bean Validation**

The `Bean Validation` API lets you validate your beans, with the `@NotNull`, `@Size`, and all the other annotations of the `javax.validation.constraints` package.

You can use a `Validator` to validate your beans and get a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` with all the `ConstraintViolation` with the info of the property.

JPA/Hibernate supports the `Bean Validation` API. If the `<validation-mode>` element in `persistence.xml` is set to `AUTO` (or it's not set, as `AUTO` is the default value), JPA will validate entities prior to saving them with a `Validator`, and throw a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` if there are any `ConstraintViolation`s, only if an implementation of `Bean Validation` is present on the environment. If you set `<validation-mode>` to `CALLBACK`, JPA will always validate the entities and will throw an error during deployment if there is not a `Bean Validation` implementation on the environment.

**SQL Constraints**

JPA annotations, like `@Column` provide information to generate your database DDL. Using `@Column(nullable = false, length = 10)` will generates a database column with a maximum length of 10 and a `NOT NULL` SQL constraint. But that's it. Hibernate don't check this before sending the statement to the database.

If a `null` value is provided, the database will report an SQL Error, that will be mapped to a `SQLException` by the JDBC driver. The error message in the `SQLException` will be different for each DBMS, but will contain the constraint name. Hibernate wraps this exceptions in a `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` that extracts the constraint name from the SQLException message.

**Conclusion**

- Set `<validation-mode>` to `CALLBACK` on your `persistence.xml` to make sure validation is always performed and invalid values don't hit the database
- Use `javax.validation.constraints` annotations to mach the SQL column constraints, for example, a not null column with a max size of 50:

  @NotNull @Size(max = 50)
  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
- Provide meaningful names for unique constraints and foreign key constraints, as this will be the only info you can get to identify what constraint is violated.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you recommended, used matching ```javax.validation.constraints``` annotations and am validating them with the Validator class. However, I decided it's best to check unique constraints and foreign key constraints by myself (before saving the entity to the database) because everything else is just too much hassle and might also cause security risks.

Comment: You can check foreign keys, using `entityManager.find` and checking for `null`, or using `entityManger.getReference` and catching `EntityNotFoundException`, but in the case of unique keys, you surely can do a query before saving your entity, but that will not always work if there is concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61560286/144578) by Areus explains to not confuse Hibernate validator and the database constraints, but building on that, it's not always easy to fetch the affected column name from the database exception that you get. For instance when you have a unique constraint on the database column it's hard to properly return this exception to the user.

What I did was have a class that handles my REST call exception handling and finds that specific exception message. I found no other way to do this yet in Spring/Hibernate.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> dataIntegrityViolationException(final DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        String mostSpecificCauseMessage = e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage();
        if (e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            String name = ((ConstraintViolationException) e.getCause()).getConstraintName();
            log.debug("Encountered ConstraintViolationException, details: " + mostSpecificCauseMessage);
            return determineError(mostSpecificCauseMessage, name);
        } else {
            log.debug("Encountered DataIntegrityViolation exception, details: " + mostSpecificCauseMessage);
            ErrorDTO errorDTO =
                new ErrorDTO("BAD_REQUEST_ERROR", "DataIntegrityViolation exception. " + mostSpecificCauseMessage);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    //this catches the manually invoked entityManager.flush() exceptions
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> constraintViolationException(final ConstraintViolationException e) {
        String message = e.getMessage();
        String name = e.getConstraintName();
        log.debug("Encountered ConstraintViolationException, details: {}", message);
        return determineError(message, name);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> determineError(String message, String name) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        switch (name) {
            case Project.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME:
                errors.put("name", ALREADY_EXISTS);
                break;
            case Value.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VALUE:
                errors.put("value", ALREADY_EXISTS);
                break;
            //and so on
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            ErrorDTO error = new ErrorDTO(VALIDATION_ERROR, VALIDATION_ERROR_MESSAGE, errors);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO("CONFLICT_ERROR", message);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDTO, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to define the constraint name in your Model entity/database, such as:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VALUE, columnNames = {"value"})})

public static final String UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_VALUE = "unique_constraint_property_value";
```

And in the database definition as well of course.

Comment: Can you post ErrorDto class? What is Project and Value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I apologize for my terrible level of English (I used google translator as best I can)

I imagine this is not the best way to solve this, but it worked for me:

Given that in the database, in the design of the table, we can see the correspondence between the name of the index and that of the field, I make a Map where I store them for later use

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeI1F.png)

```
public class ApiUniqueViolationException {

private String fieldname;

private String value;

public ApiUniqueViolationException(Exception ex) {
    initForeigns(ex);
}

private void initForeigns(Exception ex){
    Map<String, String> foreigns = new HashMap<>();
    foreigns.put("UK_ob8kqyqqgmefl0aco34akdtpe", "email");
    if ( ex.getMessage().contains("Duplicate entry") ) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Duplicate entry '(.*?)' for key");
        String message = ex.getMessage();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String match = matcher.group(1);
            String key = ((ConstraintViolationException)ex.getCause()).getConstraintName();
            this.setValue(match);
            this.setFieldname(foreigns.get(key));
        }
    }
}

public String getFieldname() {
    return fieldname;
}

public void setFieldname(String fieldname) {
    this.fieldname = fieldname;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

Response from swagger
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNt1w.png)